# how to create Kindle fire device in geny motion?

Tags: android-virtual-device, genymotion

Hi I want to create device for kindle fire tab using 'Genymotion' but can't see any device for that so can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i know, there is no Amazon device available on Genymotion pre-configured device list. You need use a Generic Device to test :(

I believe that, further informations or requests can submitted right at https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/support/